# Count Total number of slide loop and show only those PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

PHP show total number of Active slides what I'm using

I have 5 sliders but if user upload only 2 slides then loop still continue. I want to stop loop after last slide.

I'm using setting for images : slideimg1, slideimg2, slideimg3....slideimg5 (same for link and text)

```
$slider_flag = false;
                for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
                    if ( get_theme_mod('slideimg'.$i, true) != "" ) {
                        echo "<a href='".esc_url(get_theme_mod('slidebnlink'.$i, true))."'>
<img src='".get_theme_mod('slideimg'.$i, true)."' title='".get_theme_mod('slidebntext'.$i, true)."'></a>";                      
                        $slider_flag = true; }
```

I'm thing that last value of image call in and stop there

```
echo $input = get_theme_mod('slideimg'.$i);
echo $newString = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", '', $input);
```

but this return error and image link string remove only.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your slides in an array. https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array.php
And then:

```
    $arr = array(slide1, slide2, slide3,...);
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $value; //Your slide
    }
```